# deep copy object array properties value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take a look at this snippet:

```
$.extend( true, {}, { key: ["somevalue"] }, { key: ["anothervalue"] })
```

doing this I expect the produced object will contain a property called "key"
which is an array and has 2 elements, e.g

```
{ key: ["somevalue", "anothervalue"] }
```

Am I just giving the deep copy more than it can handle?

Answer (score 1):

Nop !! The result will be a object containing key having value ["anothervalue"], you are basically overriding the "key" as you pass more objects in the arguments with key as "key"

Thanks